# Animate NavigationBar up/down based on content offset

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, scrollview

I would like to implement Twitter's Navigation Bar animation. When you scroll up (Table View or Collection View) the Navigation Bar is animated up with the content and then pinned to the Safe Area Insets.  It is then animated down when the content is scrolled down.

So far I have a Navigation Bar that animates up with my Table View scrolling up but only scrolls down when the whole list reaches the top. How would I go about adding the below functionality?

1. Pin the bottom of the Navigation Bar to the Safe Area Insets
2. Animate the Navigation Bar Back in when the user scrolls down

### Working Code

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Safe Area Insets
        let topAreaInset: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter{$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0
        // Nav Bar Height
        let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0
        // Total Offset
        let yOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y + navigationBarHeight + topAreaInset
        // Move NavigationBar
        navigationController?.navigationBar.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: min(0, -yOffset))
    }
```

### Code Example

[image: navigation_bar_example]

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem